# iOS - UIImage Resize to Bigger get Blurry

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to resize the UIImage

Before the UIImage:
[image]

After this code and UIImage:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (CGPointMake(155,139));
[currentImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,155,139)];
currentImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSLog(@"get size : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(currentImageView.image.size));
```

NSLog: get size : {155,139}
[image]

Last, I try to restore the size by this code. but its blurry.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (OriginalSize);
[currentImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,OriginalSize.width,OriginalSize.height)];
currentImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSLog(@"get size : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(cnurrentImageView.image.size));
```

NSLog: get size : {1024,352}
[image]

What happened?
Have any suggestions and advice?

Comment: Well you lost data when you made the image smaller, than when you make the image bigger that is lost and you will the pixel, that the blur. It's not like CSI where you can just blow up an image and that you will get a sharp image, that is totally not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making two mistakes,

1.Reducing the image size and setting it to a larger size imageView,
    this can be fixed with the code,

```
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

2.You have resize the original image to a smaller size, then
    resizing the smaller image to original size, this will stretch the
    image.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR 1 : first step**,

You can use this code so that the image quality doesn't loose:

Instead of

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
```

Use

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(currentImageView.frame.size, NO, 0);
```

as the size you want is smaller and the imageview is larger so you also need to set

```
YourimageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

**For Second Step :**

Use original image to resize it.